# twitter follow button and facebook like button not working on resizing window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 css framework.

I added facebook like buttona and twitter follow button. It works when I don't resize the window. When I resize my window, twitter and facebook buttons appear but I cannot click on it (there is no hyperlink mouse sign when i hover over these buttons)

[image: This is working]

[image: when i resize the window and when the point reaches such that the buttons move to next row, buttons are no more click-able]

when i resize the window and when the point reaches such that the buttons move to next row, buttons are no more click-able
how can i fix this ?

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:4px;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px; background:#09C;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="padding-bottom:4px;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">Go</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
<!-- my social buttons are here-->
<!-- facebook and twitter are embedded inside iframe
</div></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VZk5G/

Comment: _Please_ stop using inline styles!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a link to your site?

Comment: jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/VZk5G/
@Bojangles thanks for the tip, i will be assigning them classes later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with the *.col-md-3* class is hovering the div with those buttons (*.col-md-5*). Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to fix that:

```
.col-md-3
{
    z-index: 2;
}
.col-md-5
{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

A working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VZk5G/1/)